# Configuration Error: Error for provider in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, provider

I'm migrating from entityframework 6.1.0 to entityframework 5.0.0. I've installed EntityFramework 5.0.0 successfully.

Now I'm having problem in web.config.

This is my web.config:

```
<configSections>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>

<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MusicStoreEntities" connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;initial catalog=MvcMusicStore;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\MvcMusicStore.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

I didn't have this problem before with EF 6.1.0.

I've searched a lot but I could not find a solution for my problem.

Thanks...

Comment: That's your entire Web.config file?

Comment: What's the exact error message you get in Visual Studio?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: the copy operation wasn't performed well. Now you can see my web.config

Comment: @LenielMacaferi: A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll and Unrecognized element 'providers' in web.config

Comment: Your problem is likely with `<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />`; the namespaces may be different in the older version.

Comment: @bahar_Agi, what happens when you just remove `<providers>`; just comment it out.

Comment: Yes, I know but what should I set for provider? I've could'nt find solution

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: When I commented it, it seems that have problem with connecting to database

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

Here's more info from EF site regarding [Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx#Providers) only necessary in EF 6 ownwards.

---

Make sure you have LocalDb NuGet package installed:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.LocalDb
```

Comment: I've tried to remove it but It has problem in connecting to db

Comment: an exception in initializing the the database

Comment: @bahar_Agi sure... but we need the exact error message like in inner exception...

Comment: Could not determine storage version; a valid storage connection or a version hint is required.

Comment: @bahar_Agi: related to your problem: http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/02/moving-from-entity-framework-5-to-entity-framework-6-and-back-or-could-not-determine-storage-version/

Comment: What does this :  Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.LocalDb do?

Comment: @bahar_Agi it's necessary because you're using LocalDb in your connection string. It's a provider.